# ROC Curve for decision tree

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, roc, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to plot a ROC Curve for Decision tree. But with calculating the confusion matrix, it takes too much time to compute for each threshold. So is there a better way to compute the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

in your confusion_matrix method,
You can cache the predictions to optimize the performance

```
 def confusion_matrix(predictions):
     # Calculate the elements of the confusion matrix
    predictions.cache()
    TN = predictions.filter('prediction = 0 AND label = 0').count()
    TP = predictions.filter('prediction = 1 AND label = 1').count()
    FN = predictions.filter('prediction = 0 AND label = 1').count()
    FP = predictions.filter('prediction = 1 AND label = 0').count()
    predictions.unpersist()
    return TP,TN,FP,FN
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use the scikit-learn implementation, you just need to provide an array with the true values and another with the predictions: [sklearn.metrics.roc_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html)

Comment: OP is clearly in a "big data" framework: they are using Pyspark, implying that the dataframes involved cannot fit into the memory of a single machine, so scikit-learn is not applicable here.